# An estimate involving gaps in a subsemigroup of $(\mathbb N,+)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, number-theory, semigroups

I think this question can be solved by a high school student, maybe there is some trick on it or I'm forgetting something.

Before my question, some background is required:

> **Definition:** A numerical semigroup is a subsemigroup $H$ of the additive semigroup $\mathbb N$ of the non-negative integers such that
>   $\mathbb N-H$ is finite and $0\in H$. A numerical semigroup has genus $g$ if
>   $L=\mathbb N-H$ has $g$ elements. The elements of $L$, $1=l_1\lt l_2\lt
>  \ldots\lt l_g$, are called gaps of $H$, while the elements of $H$,
>   $0=n_0\lt n_1\lt \ldots$ are called non-gaps of $H$. If $n_1=2$ the semigroup is called hyperelliptic.

Using this definition, I'm trying to understand this little piece of the proof of this theorem:

[image]

So, my question is why $l_j-(2j-r)\in H$? I almost sure it's a silly thing.

I realized after some days that perhaps this problem is genuinely a combinatorial one.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How does this have anything to do with algebraic geometry, or algebraic curves?

Comment: @AlexYoucis: these semigroups arise as the possible orders of a pole of a rational function at a point on a curve; and I assume that's the context in this paper. (Note the giveaway words "genus" and "hyperelliptic".) It's true that the question itself doesn't need that background, but people who know about curves may well be in the best position to answer.

Comment: Please don't make trivial edits in order to "bump" your question.

Comment: @MikeMiller Ok, thank you for the remark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why this is so is because of the statement in the previous paragraph that "if the equality holds then each pair $(n, \ell_j-n)$ has a gap and a non-gap" (I'm renaming the variable here to prevent confusion).  Since we have that $k = 2j-r\in L$, it must be the case that $\ell_j-k\in H$.

Meanwhile, the reason for this statement is a basic pigeonhole argument: there are $j-1$ pairs of the form $(n, \ell_j-n)$ and only $j-1$ gaps less than $\ell_j$.  Because no pair can have zero gaps (because then $n\in H$ and $\ell_j-n\in H$, so $\ell_j = n+(\ell_j-n)\in H$, contradiction), no pair can have more than one gap (or the total count of gaps would be $\gt j-1$); therefore, each pair has a gap and a non-gap.